# Disable Drag and Drop tabs in FIREFOX

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, firefox-profile

1) Is there a way to disable drag and drop of tabs in firefox and only enable it when I drag tabs while holding the control button?

2) A way to undo the last drag and drop using a keyboard shortcut?

I searched online but all I can find is the add-ons to lock tabs and such.
Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to use the addons?

Comment: well, I don't really want to use an add-on for such a small task as add-ons are usually full of bloat and will provide a million other features other than this single feature.
I was looking for something along the lines of editing about:config or some other internal settings file if possible.
but if that's not possible and u have any good add-on suggestion which could help me with this then please feel free to let me know.
Any help is better than no help. :)) I really appreciate any help given. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Without using plug-ins there is not a way to prevent tab dragging in Firefox, or to limit it to only dragging when a key is pressed.

A brief web search made this clear and also pointed out a few plug-ins that may work. We don't recommend software products here though. Just do a quick web search though and you'll find any plug-ins that do this.

Comment: "Without using plug-ins there is not a way to prevent tab dragging in Firefox" -- there's the about:config preference `browser.tabs.allowTabDetach`

Comment: "plugin" doesn't refer to addons https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Plugins and they have separate page in about:addons

Comment: OP doesn't want to globally disable, but to set a control factor that prevents it from occurring just with a mouse click.

Comment: "plugin" and "add on" are synonymous in general use unless context indicates otherwise. If you have an answer, post it.

Comment: Posted an an answer, hopefully acceptable even though the question isn't fully addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the preference `browser.tabs.allowTabDetach` to `false` in [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox), but sadly I'm not aware of a way to only enable the functionality when holding a key.